# Get data between two timeuuids in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I want to get data between two dates '2015-07-11 12:00:00' and '2015-07-12 15:00:00'. The column which stores date and time is timeuuid.
What will be the query? I am new to cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
   WHERE t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')
   AND t < minTimeuuid('2013-02-02 10:00+0000')
```